# Can't find phonegap.js or phonegap.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, installation

I am new to Phonegap. I am trying to install Phonegap in my Windows OS for Android. I am using  [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=519auOITpzM).

In this tutorial, they say to copy phonegap.js and phonegap.jar files to some folders. But I haven't downloaded anything. I have installed Phonegap in my pc with this command `npm install -g phonegap`. Where can I find these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cordova version 3.0.0 they are not giving zip file on their website. You can either download previous versions or you can get it from Github.